# Resize listview columns on ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility change

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I am using a [star converter to have relative sized listview columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338930/how-to-resize-wpf-listview-proportionally/11421253#11421253), but my current problem is that this does not take into account if the scrollbar is visible or not. I tried to add something like the following into the code:

```
  var scroll = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listView);
  var offset = 0.0;
  if (scroll.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
    offset = SystemParameters.ScrollWidth + 5;
```

But, the sizing is done before the scrollbar visibility and the scroll is always being shown as `Collapsed`.

So, my question is, how can I resize my columns appropriately. I have tried to add a trigger on `ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility`, but have not had any success there. I tried to use [custom code based off of this link](http://blog.vascooliveira.com/wpf-listview-styling-tutorial-part-ii/), but always end up with a blank listview currently (may be due to the listview using an ItemsPresenter, but I am not sure currently).

Here is the listview setup that I have tried:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#999999" >
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="blah" >
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="blah" Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger  SourceName="blah" Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="blah"  Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The setters are just to see if it works...but they are never set at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a kind of hack. [Here is my initial blog post](http://justin-pihony.blogspot.com/2012/07/wpf-resize-listview-columns-on.html) on it as it can get quite long. I still need to clean up the code, but hopefully it helps others